# Docker rename a host user

Tags: docker

Can I use a generic username in container, which will get mapped to the --user entry passed while launching the container? Is there anyway to accomplish this?
The UID should remain the same, so that the host users permissions will reflect inside the container.

Comment: Do you *need* to specify a user while running the container?

Comment: The UID should remain the same as what? Previous containers, the image value, the host value, or something else?

Comment: Does it matter if the numeric user ID has a name?  For many applications it works just fine to start a container with a numeric user ID even if that user doesn't "exist" in `/etc/passwd` or elsewhere.  Also consider if you can make your container more isolated from the host system (maybe it can store data in a database instead of a shared-with-the-host directory) so the user ID doesn't matter.

Comment: I'm passing -v option to reuse credentials from host system. There were some hard coded mount paths and fstab entries which require a predefined username.